# Add more fields in Custom Big Objec

Tags: big-object

Anybody there to help me out how to add more fields in custom Big Object?

I had already created one Custom Big Object with some fields. Now Im trying to add more fields in the same Object. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your point. The easiest way is by including the new fields in the same .object and permission set file and deploy it using workbench.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the Metadata API to define a big object or add a field to a custom big object. [(see the documentation)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm)

You can use the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) to deal with the MetaData API like below

- First, do a retrieve from your org using [sf:retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_retrieve_unpackaged.htm)
- Second, Edit the file **YOUR_BIG_OBJECT**.object retrieved to add some `<Fields>` like [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_define.htm)
- Finally, You can deploy your edited file **YOUR_BIG_OBJECT**.object with the [sf:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_code.htm)

Comment: Can the retrieving step here be done via workbench's retrieve tool?