# Retrieve a pre-existing big object via metadata in order to add new fields

Tags: metadata, workbench, big-object

**Goal**

1. Retrieve a pre-existing big object in salesforce.
2. Add new Fields to the metadata
3. and deploy it back to the same org

**Question**

Can this be done via the workbenches retrieve tool?

**Steps Taken so far**

I found a previous post with some steps to do this via the [ANT migration tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/200385/62451).

So I tried to replicate the steps accept using workbench. I attempted to retrieve the record using the following package.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DCT__b</name>
    </types>
  <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

And got the following:

[image]

[image: problem: Entity type: 'DCT__b' is unknown]

"problem: Entity type: 'DCT__b' is unknown"

So im definitely doing this wrong.  But im struggling to find resources or posts on it. Anyone have advice or resources on how to accomplish my goals above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<name>` element of the `package.xml` is the name of the metadata entity you wish to retrieve. The API names of the individual items within that entity which you desire go in the `<members>` elements.

Here, you need to do something like this:

```
<types>
    <members>DCT__b</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

The Metadata API functionality is at its core the same regardless of which tool you use (Workbench, Ant, SFDX, CumulusCI, and so on).

Comment: Thank you David, that fixed it!